# How To Upload a file With out Page Refreshing in Asp.net Mvc asp x engine

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

i want upload a XML file in jquery popup with out page refresh

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid page refresh? You need some sort of post to the server, and this will usually mean page refresh unless you upload the file through a non-html upload control (like a flash one, or connecting to the server through sockets/webrequests, etc...)

Comment: because in page refresh event doument.redy() is calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's easy for the client side, a simple ajax call will do the work on the headers

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo">
    <input type="file" name="file" required />
</form>

var data = new FormData();
data.append('element',$(this)[0].files[0])
$.ajax(
{ 
    url : 'Your controller action',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
})
```

Server side it's a action and you can recieve this value

```
public ActionResult UploadXml(HttpPostedFileBase dataXml)
{
    dataXml.SaveAs("string with the path");
    return View();
}
```

This is not suppored by IE only for webkit ff and IE from 10

Answer (score 0):

Try these: supports both synchronous/Asynchronous uploading that you require:

[Kendo UI File Upload for MVC](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/upload/index.html)

[Telerik File Upload for MVC](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/upload) *contains extra example if you want to understand the implementation*

However, If you are new to MVC/jQuery `Kendo UI` could be of great help and fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Telerik Extension for MVC upload. It's open source. find @ http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/ and demo @ http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/upload

Comment: You can use other controls as well.